# hadoop Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

I am executing this program on hdfs.

```
package abc;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class mycls {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(URI.create("https://localhost:19000"), new Configuration());

        Path homeDir = hdfs.getHomeDirectory();

        System.out.println("Home Folder: " + homeDir);

        Path workingDir = hdfs.getWorkingDirectory();

        System.out.println("Working Folder: " + workingDir);

    }

}
```

But i keep getting this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: https
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
    at abc.mycls.main(mycls.java:11)
```

I have added all the jar files to access hadoop on eclipse. I am working on windows 10, hadoop-2.7.4 and jdk-1.8.

Comment: What is running on `locahost:19000`... I don't believe there is an HTTPS FS implementation. Are you trying to access HDFS over WebHDFS?

Comment: Actually I'm new to this hadoop environment so I don't know much about it.
I don't know about webHDFS. localhost:19000 is my localhost, I wrote it in coresite.xml file.

Comment: That didn't really answer my question. What application is running on port 19000? Or, what application do you expect to be running on port 19000? In other words why are you doing `URI.create("https://localhost:19000")`? If you can post the snippet of `core-site.xml` that contains this URL, that would also help.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. It was my mistake. Use `create("hdfs://localhost:19000")` instead of `create("https://localhost:19000")`.